What is the minimum tank size for two snails (Nassarius and Nerite)?
I was wondering if you could help answer a question for me. What is the minimum tank size necessary for a Nassarius and Nerite Snail (saltwater)? My local fish shop has told me any size but wanted to make sure.
I love these little buddies and want to ensure I am not accidentally causing them any harm.
Thank you so much!
